# Why is this specific pose so prevalent in the MCU at the moment?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Recently I noticed this oddly specific pose, which I am now dubbing the Super Hero Holds Two Things Together Pose (or SHHTTTP for short), has appeared from what I can tell at least six times in the MCU, possibly more.

[image: Thor keeping the forge open on Nedavallir]

[image: Spider-Man holding two ships together]

[image: The first known instance of the SHHTTTP, Captain America holding a helicopter down in Civil War.]

You will of course notice that I only have three pictured instances of the SHHTTTP here, well the three others I've noticed I couldn't find pictures for, but that definitely do exist are: Gamora keeping Drax tethered to the ship in *GOTG Vol 2*, Spider-Man keeping Doctor Strange from being abducted by the flying doughnut in *Infinity War* and Thanos being briefly restrained by both arms in the battle on Τitan (also in *Infinity War*).

Obviously there is no in-universe explanation for why this is so common, however is there an out-of-universe explanation? Does Kevin Feige just really like pectoral muscles or something? Am I just insane and seeing patterns where there are none?

Any other known examples of the SHHTTTP in Superhero media would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: +1 for "Wackiest question subject that, in the end, I really couldn't argue with."

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrucifiedHeroShot

Comment: @Valorum From that page: "The "person with outstretched arms symbolically representing Christ" pose is so deeply ingrained into modern culture that anytime we see a character in that pose, we tend to assume the director was going for this trope, even when it's obvious from the context of the scene that he or she *wasn't*". Did the director mean to say that Captain America died for our sins? You make the call!

Comment: There **is** an in-universe explanation:   The heroes just keep having to hold two things together.

Comment: That's sort of a joke, but really, how could there ever be an in-universe explanation besides that?   What?  Some all-encompassing force in the MCU universe keeps pushing things apart that should be together?   There can't be an in-universe explanation of any interest.

Comment: Why _not_? Massive biceps: Check. Struggling on both sides: Check. Slow-motion view of the hero using all of their force to overcome a challenge: Check.

Comment: @Möoz  - Precisely so. If Thor hadn't been so buff, he'd have found a non-hero-pose method to hold the thingies together,

Comment: @Möoz:   Are you responding to me?   Slow-motion doesn't exist in-universe.   There seems to be confusion about what an in-universe explanation can be.    Valorum's point is technically correct -->  the heroes might not use this pose if they were even stronger.   But what makes all the heroes exactly strong enough that they can do what they need with the pose and not less.   This is just not a productive discussion regarding an in-universe explanation.   We're descending into ludicrosity.

Comment: Even on the Netflix series! Jessica Jones holding some elevator cables together.

Comment: Isn't that kind of spiderman's usual _modus operandi_? Think about him stopping the runaway train in SM2? Talk about your "crucified hero" - including how he was treated _after_ he stopped the thing.

Comment: Have you also noticed the whole MCU is lit in orange and blue?

Comment: Orange and blue colour palates are present in a lot of modern day films. weridly marvel is one of the least guilty of this, relatively speaking.

Comment: "Crucifiied Hero Shot" might be the most relevant and direct answer to this question. The themes are wrapped up in that too. This also happens to be a much more visual and dramatic feat of strength that plays well on screen... better than say, throwing a heavy thing, which happens too much to look special. It's important to know that Cap and Spidey really are buff as hell so that we can see them tango believably with the big guys.

Comment: Look, we can't all do [big-arms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THa3RLTT9PA).

Comment: I believe there's a making of or commentary of the scene from Civil War where the producers describe it as "bicep porn".

Comment: If you want prior examples of this, how about Sam Raimi Spiderman trying to stop that train? Or Batman Begins Batman trying to lift Ras'al'Ghul back onto a cliff? Or the Incredibles Elastigirl holding the van onto that plane near the end? I think it's just a common pose, one where the audience can understand that it's a difficult task for the hero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure 6+ instances from around 48 hours of footage is "prevalent".  There are far more superman like poses, or people standing, leaning on things, even sitting, but we don't look for meaning in those.

As one of the comments said (**and really they should take all the credit**), there just happens to be scenes where things had to be held together (or pulled apart) where legs can't be on the ground, showing that even though this character had good like super immense strength for whatever [origin] reason, is still giving their all to try to save humanity (or vogonity if there is any sign of poetry), because succeeding is more important than pain when the universe is at stake.

I think you're looking for a reason that isn't there.  If it was in every film, and maybe more than once in some films, or if it was always the same character then I'd say you're on to something.  But there are far more other stances that are far more prevalent with little to know reason.

Even Deadpool made fun of how painful and impractical the main landing stance of an average superhero is.

***But this is just my opinion, i can't back it up with any facts whatsoever***

Answer (score 6):

The SHHTTTP is a subcategory of a common trope in many films: the [crucified hero pose](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrucifiedHeroShot).

> It's very common for a character who just performed a [Heroic Sacrifice](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HeroicSacrifice) to be lying with their arms outstretched like the crucified Jesus.
>
> Note that characters who stand with outstretched arms aren't necessarily meant to represent this pose; they can also symbolise bird wings, in the sense of freedom. Or angel wings, as a mix of both.

See the above link for a list of examples, but the movie that made me start looking for this pose everywhere was the Matrix.

[image]

> Any other known examples of the SHHTTTP in Superhero media would also be very much appreciated.

The link above contains a list of a bunch of superhero comics and movies. Here are a few examples I can think of:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Crucified", yes, but I would not say the three last ones are "holding two things together"...

Comment: @Jenayah I don't disagree with you. I guess I'd say the SHHTTTP is a subset of the jesus pose.

Answer (score 2):

### The pose demonstrates the hero's heroic willpower while also looking cool

The SHHTTTP is difficult, painful, static, and *optional*.  In most cases the hero in this pose is suffering, but the suffering is entirely voluntary because the hero is capable of letting go at any moment.

This means that the hero, in addition to showing off their immense strength also demonstrates how heroic they are.  Punching villains is all well and good, but rarely causes the heroes pain (generally it's the other way around).  Getting beat up is generally not voluntary, and doesn't show off the hero's strength.

Having the hero protect a person or object from an oncoming attack can have a similar effect, but it's a lot harder to produce a long tracking shot of a high speed collision. (That said, you do get at least one example in Infinity War, when Captain America holds Thanos' fist open).  Holding two things together is generally static  (the whole point is to keep the objects from moving after all), so it lends itself to long dramatic shots.

(A lot of the symbolism I've described here applies to the Crucified Hero shot in general, but it's strongest in this particular pose.)